# Spring Integration how to get file from many ftp server and dirictory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-ftp

I'm trying to set up fetching new files from multiple ftp servers and directories for post-processing.
At the moment, only the first server from the collection is connected. Tell me what I'm doing wrong.

With my implementation, I see that there is no transition to the second server and errors appear:
**1.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: IOException when retrieving**

FtpConfiguration.java

```
@Log4j2
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/ftp.properties")
public class FtpConfiguration {

@Value("${sftp.name}")
private String[] names;
@Value("${sftp.host}")
private String[] hosts;
@Value("${sftp.user}")
private String[] users;
@Value("${sftp.pwd}")
private String[] pwds;

private final MessageService messageService;

@Autowired
public FtpConfiguration(MessageService messageService) {
    this.messageService = messageService;
}


@Bean
public DelegatingSessionFactory<FTPFile> delegatingSessionFactory() {
    Map<Object, SessionFactory<FTPFile>> factories = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(this.hosts[i]);
        factory.setUsername(this.users[i]);
        factory.setPassword(this.pwds[i]);
        factory.setClientMode(2);
        factories.put(this.names[i], factory);
    }
    return new DelegatingSessionFactory<>(factories, factories.values().iterator().next());
}

@Bean
public RotatingServerAdvice advice() {
    List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = new ArrayList<>();
    keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory(this.names[0], "/test"));
    keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory(this.names[1], "/prod"));
    return new RotatingServerAdvice(delegatingSessionFactory(), keyDirectories, true);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpIntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Ftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(template())
                    .remoteDirectory("."),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(500).advice(advice())))
            .transform(new StreamTransformer("UTF-8"))
            .handle(message -> {
                log.info("Read file: {}", message.getHeaders()
                        .get("file_remoteDirectory" + "/" + message.getHeaders()
                                .get("file_remoteFile")));
                messageService.unmarshall(message);
            })
            .get();
}

@Bean
public FtpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
    return new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(delegatingSessionFactory());
}
```

}

ftp.properties

```
sftp.name=test,prod
sftp.host=10.10.10.11,10.10.10.12
sftp.user=user1,user2
sftp.pwd=pass1,pass2
```

The first server is polled, gets the file, goes to the second, and an error occurs. If I change the server places, then it also receives one file from the server, it goes to another error, it goes to the first one, it gets it successfully.
I would like to take all the files from one server, when I ended up moving to another, so can I do it?

Stack trace

```
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:07:23.352 [task-scheduler-1] DefaultFtpSessionFactory - Connected to server [10.10.10.12:21]
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:07:42.592 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:07:42.592 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:08:10.543 [task-scheduler-1] FtpSession - failed to disconnect FTPClient
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58) ~[commons-net-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:320) ~[commons-net-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:299) ~[commons-net-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:731) ~[commons-net-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.completePendingCommand(FTPClient.java:1861) ~[commons-net-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.finalizeRaw(FtpSession.java:114) ~[spring-integration-ftp-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.close(FtpSession.java:155) ~[spring-integration-ftp-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.remoteFileToMessage(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:230) ~[spring-integration-file-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:210) ~[spring-integration-file-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:45) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.aop.ReceiveMessageAdvice.invoke(ReceiveMessageAdvice.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.receive(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:408) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:377) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$3(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:321) ~[spring-integration-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95) [spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

```
[INFO ] 2021-03-17 23:08:10.554 [task-scheduler-1] FtpStreamingMessageSource - Removing the remote file 'FileInfo [isDirectory=false, isLink=false, Size=4792, ModifiedTime=Tue Mar 09 00:24:00 MSK 2021, Filename=XX.xml, RemoteDirectory=/test, Permissions=----------]' from the filter for a subsequent transfer attempt
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:08:10.555 [task-scheduler-1] PublishSubscribeChannel - preSend on channel 'bean 'errorChannel'', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: IOException when retrieving /test/XX.xml, headers={id=37cd10d7-41fd-0ac8-2630-14fd8c3a3cd5, timestamp=1616011690555}]
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:08:10.555 [task-scheduler-1] LoggingHandler - bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler' for component '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: IOException when retrieving /test/XX.xml, headers={id=37cd10d7-41fd-0ac8-2630-14fd8c3a3cd5, timestamp=1616011690555}]
[ERROR] 2021-03-17 23:08:10.556 [task-scheduler-1] LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: IOException when retrieving /test/XX.xml
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:391)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$3(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:321)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: IOException when retrieving /test/XX.xml
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.remoteFileToMessage(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:45)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.integration.aop.ReceiveMessageAdvice.invoke(ReceiveMessageAdvice.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:408)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:377)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/XX.xml: 550
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.readRaw(FtpSession.java:104)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.remoteFileToMessage(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:221)
    ... 37 more

[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:08:10.557 [task-scheduler-1] PublishSubscribeChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'errorChannel'', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: IOException when retrieving /test/XX.xml, headers={id=37cd10d7-41fd-0ac8-2630-14fd8c3a3cd5, timestamp=1616011690555}]
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:08:11.075 [task-scheduler-2] DefaultFtpSessionFactory - Connected to server [10.10.10.11:21]
[DEBUG] 2021-03-17 23:08:11.201 [task-scheduler-2] SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=org.apache.commons.net.io.SocketInputStream@77de7f0a,
```

Comment: Can we see the whole stack trace, please? Nothing obvious at the moment with your code. All looks good.

Comment: Added information from the stack trace and a description of the current behavior

Comment: The FTP `550` error code is out of Spring Integration control: https://bobcares.com/blog/ftp-550-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: Error 550 when there is a connection to the second server, before that, the transfer is successful from the first.  If I change the server in places in advice() then the transfer occurs, but when connecting to the second, error 550

Comment: I can't think about something what could be a reason. Unless you can configure it like this `return new DelegatingSessionFactory<>(factories, null);` and there is indeed no `key` populated to the `ThreadLocal`. There are also some TRACE logs you can investigate, too, e.g. `this.logger.trace("Next poll is for " + this.current);`. Consider to enable `TRACE` for the `org.springframework.integration` category to see what is going on in logs.

Comment: In the debug, I found a stripe where it goes to the second server and FtpSession - failed to disconnect FTPClient. Stack trace attached. Maybe you can tell by it what is going wrong.

Comment: removed the fair parameter in the RotatingServerAdvice constructor and everything worked. AS IS: return new RotatingServerAdvice(delegatingSessionFactory(), keyDirectories, true); TO BE: return new RotatingServerAdvice(delegatingSessionFactory(), keyDirectories);

Comment: `Connection reset` just means the server had already closed the connection when we tried to close it. 550 is. `Permission Denied`.

Comment: Yeah... But his point that it works without `fair`, so sounds like some race condition when with switch between servers on each poll call.